# Search not working using jQuery with call to json

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

What i am trying to do is, i have an input field. Upon entering something in the input field if am sending request to the php file which outputs json, what i want is to get the results from the json based on the input in the search field.

**index.html**

```
<input type="text" id="search-json-input" />
<input type="button" id="search-json-submit" value="search" />
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="button" name="next" id="next" value="NEXT" />
<br/>
<input type="button" name="previous" id="previous" value="PREV" />
<br/>

<div id="divuseriemail"></div>
<div id="divusersex"></div>
<div id="divuserlocation"></div>
<div id="divuserimage"></div>
<div id="divuseraudio"></div>
<div id="divuservideo"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">

var users = [];
var idx = 0; 

var url = "json.php";
var search_query = jQuery('#search-json-input').val();
var search_query_regex = new RegExp(".*"+search_query+".*", "g");
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {

    users = data.members;

    renderRow(idx);
    $('#next').click(function() {
        idx++;
        renderRow(idx);
    });
    $('#previous').click(function() {
        idx--;
        renderRow(idx);
    });
});

$("#search-json-submit").click(function(){


    for(var y=0;y<users.length;y++){ 
        //console.log(users[y]);
        if((users[y].email).match(search_query_regex) ||
            (users[y].sex).match(search_query_regex) ||
            (users[y].location).match(search_query_regex)) 
        {
            //console.log(users[y].email);
            renderRow(y)
        }
     }
});

var renderRow = function (idx) {
    //alert(idx);
    if (idx < 0) idx = 0;
    if (idx > (users.length - 1)) idx = (users.length - 1);
    var user = users[idx];

    var email = user.email;
    $('#divuseremail').html(email);
    var sex = user.sex;
    $('#divusersex').html(sex);
    var location = user.location;
    $('#divuserlocation').html(location);
    var image = "<img src=" + user.image + ">";
    $('#divuserimage').html(image);
    var audio = "<audio src=" + user.video + " controls>";
    $('#divuseraudio').html(audio);
    var video = "<video src=" + user.video + " controls>";
    $('#divuservideo').html(video);
};

</script>
```

json output: http://sco7.com/components/phonegap/json.php

Comment: Have you run this through a javascript debugger, all modern browsers have one.

Comment: @RiggsFolly actually i am getting all the results after .match, you can see i have used console.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to my code and now everything is working.

Here is the working code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery PHP Json Response</title>
<style type="text/css">
div
{
text-align:center;
padding:10px;
}

#msg {
width: 500px;
margin: 0px auto;
}
.members {
width: 500px ;
background-color: beige;
}
</style>
</head>
<body><input type="text" id="search-json-input" />
<input type="button" id="search-json-submit" value="search" />
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="button" name="next" id="next" value="NEXT" />
<br/>
<input type="button" name="previous" id="previous" value="PREV" />
<br/>
<div id="divuseriemail"></div>
<div id="divusersex"></div>
<div id="divuserlocation"></div>
<div id="divuserimage"></div>
<div id="divuseraudio"></div>
<div id="divuservideo"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">



var users = [];
var idx = 0; 

var url = "json.php";

$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    users = data.members;
    renderRow(idx);
    $('#next').click(function() {
        idx++;
        if (idx > (users.length - 1)) idx = (users.length - 1);
        renderRow(idx);
    });
    $('#previous').click(function() {
        idx--;
        if (idx < 0) idx = 0;
        renderRow(idx);
    });
});

$("#search-json-submit").click(function(){

        var search_query = jQuery('#search-json-input').val();
    var search_query_regex = new RegExp(".*"+search_query+".*", "g");


    for(var y=0;y<users.length;y++){ 
    if((users[y].email).match(search_query_regex) ||
           (users[y].sex).match(search_query_regex) ||
   (users[y].location).match(search_query_regex)) {

        renderRow(y)

        }
     }
});

var renderRow = function (idx) {
    //alert(idx);
   // if (idx < 0) idx = 0;
    //if (idx > (users.length - 1)) idx = (users.length - 1);
    var user = users[idx];

        console.log(user);
 var email = user.email;
   $('#divuseremail').html(email);
    var sex = user.sex;
    $('#divusersex').html(sex);
    var location = user.location;
    $('#divuserlocation').html(location);
    var image = "<img src=" + user.image + ">";
    $('#divuserimage').html(image);
    var audio = "<audio src=" + user.video + " controls>";
    $('#divuseraudio').html(audio);
    var video = "<video src=" + user.video + " controls>";
    $('#divuservideo').html(video);



};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not getting the `.val()` of the input field every time you search the box. You need to repopulate the `search_query` and `search_query_regex` each time you perform a search, otherwise you'll just be searching with the original values of the input field - which, evidently, is an empty string.

Try this:

```
$("#search-json-submit").click(function(){

    // re-populate variables

    search_query = jQuery('#search-json-input').val();
    search_query_regex = new RegExp(".*"+search_query+".*", "g");

    for(var y=0;y<users.length;y++){ 

        if((users[y].email).match(search_query_regex) ||
            (users[y].sex).match(search_query_regex) ||
            (users[y].location).match(search_query_regex)) 
        {
            console.log(users[y].email);
            renderRow(y)
        }
     }
});
```

It doesn't help that there is visual feedback with or without a successful match. You might be better off giving feedback of the members, only when there is a successful search. But that is just a UX concern which I'm sure you're aware of.

Comment: @BaljeetSingh It is working for me. Please refer to the jsfiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/jehanzeb_malik/ksRva/1/.

Comment: @Jehanzeb.Malik check to see, even the next previous buttons are not working in this fiddle

Comment: @BaljeetSingh I only showed how it should work in general. You only had to make some simple changes. I have updated the fiddle for you. http://jsfiddle.net/jehanzeb_malik/ksRva/3/ . Please note that I have added try-catch so that script does not break in case of error. And I also replaced `$('#element').click(function(){});` with `$('#element').on('click', function(){});`. jQuery has deprecated the former method that you are using. And will be permanently removed in next update.

Comment: @BaljeetSingh As I said in my answer I'm unsure that the constant visual feedback in your application is helping on the de-bugging side. You might consider removing the feedback when no search has been made. But our suggestions do work in the context of searching some JSON for data.

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest you test your .match then, like this

```
var lookAtMeWithTheDebugger = users[y].email.match(search_query_regex);
    lookAtMeWithTheDebugger = users[y].sex.match(search_query_regex);
    lookAtMeWithTheDebugger = users[y].location.match(search_query_regex);
```

Put a breakpoint on the first line and check whats coming back from each .match to see which test is causing problems.

You do realise that these matches will each be returning an array
Possibly this would be a better test.

Remove the "g" option as I assume you are just interested in knowing if the string occurs and not how many times.
Then try this as a test, if nothing is found .match() returns null.

```
if( users[y].email.match(search_query_regex) != null ||
    users[y].sex.match(search_query_regex) != null   ||
    users[y].location.match(search_query_regex) != null) 
{
```

I hope this leads you towards a solution.